# Extract just the path from CSS and exclude anything after the path

Tags: php, css, regex

Using the regex below, I can extract the path from the CSS, but the result also includes the bit after the "#" and "?". Is there any way I can just extract the path

## Regex

```
url\([\s]?[\"|\']?(.*?)[\"|\']?[\s]?\)
```

## String

```
url('../fonts/Google_OpenSans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
url('../fonts/Google_OpenSans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.woff2') format('woff2')
url('../fonts/Google_OpenSans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.woff') format('woff')
url('../fonts/Google_OpenSans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.ttf') format('truetype')
url('../fonts/Google_OpenSans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.svg#OpenSans') format('svg')
```

## Expected

```
../fonts/Google_OpenSans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.eot
```

## Actual

```
../fonts/Google_OpenSans/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.eot?#iefix
```

Comment: Try `url\([\s'"]*\K[^'"()?#]+`. See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/4PFNhq/1)

Comment: Reado, did you have time to check [my approach](https://ideone.com/XL5fxu)?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
url\(\s*(["']?)([^()?#]*)(?:[#?].*?)?\1\s*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jANJV8/1/). The result will be in Group 2.

**Details**

- `url\(` - `url(` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(["']?)` - Group 1: an optional `'` or `"`
- `([^()?#]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `?`, `#`, `)` and `(`
- `(?:[#?].*?)?` - an optional substring starting with `?` or `#` and then having any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (to make it even more efficient, replace `.*?` here with `[^()]*`, cf. with [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jANJV8/2))
- `\1` - same value as captured into Group 1
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a non-regex based option, I wrote this little function that can parse a URL or path and gives an object of the correct pieces:

```
function parseURL (url) {
    url = decodeURI(url);
    let split = {}
        split["?"]    = url.split("?")
        split["path"] = split["?"][0]
        split["tmp"]  = split["?"][1].split("#")
        split["#"]    = split["tmp"][1]
        split["?"]    = split["tmp"][0]

    let params = {};

    split["?"].split("&").forEach(i => {
        let tmp = i.split("=");
        params[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }) 

    return {
        path: encodeURI(split["path"]),
        params,
        fragments: split["#"]
    }
}
```

All you need to do is get the `path` property from the returned object.

```
$ node
> parseURL("https://example.com/path/to/resource?name=param&purpose=none#extrainfo")
> {
    path: "https://example.com/path/to/resource",
    params: {
      name: "param",
      purpose: "none"
    },
    fragments: "extrainfo"
  }
>
```